# timezone Datatype in django

Tags: django, django-models

```
 class MyModel(models.Model): 
    timezone = models.CharField()
```

In the above,should timezone be stored in a char field for the below values,

```
   from pytz import all_timezones

   for t in all_timezones:
       print t

    Africa/Abidjan
    Africa/Accra
    ----
    ----
```

Comment: Good.  What's your question?  What's your problem?  This looks very nice.  Why post it?  Since there's no question, what are we supposed to do?  Vote to close it?

Comment: @S.Lott:The question is that whether the timezone field should br char or not

Comment: DO. Not. Comment. On. Your. Own. Question.  Please **UPDATE** your question to actually say the actual thing you want to know.   It helps to use "?" and other hints so that we can figure out what you need to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the name actually *matters*, I'd just store it as an offset in minutes or seconds from UTC.